# READ PHP - mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, sql

Olá, gostaria de uma ajuda com o comando abaixo. Estou tentando um *read* em uma tabela do banco de dados porém não consigo fazer o `while`, pois só mostra o último registro.

Obs.: Usando o `vardump` ela mostra o `loop` normal.

```
<?
class AppNoticiasDestaque{

    function AppNoticiasDestaque() {
        $verQ = "SELECT * FROM noticias";

        $ver = mysql_query($verQ) or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($ver) > 0) {

            while($verRow = mysql_fetch_array($ver)) {
            var_dump ($this->AppNoticiasDestaque = $verRow);
    }}
        @mysql_free_result($ver);
    }
}
?>

//resgatando o resultado
<?=$obj->AppNoticiasDestaque['titulo_noticia'] ?>
```

Comment: Se possível, utilize mysql_fetch_assoc pois é mais rápido que o mysql_fetch_array

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado. Alterado para mysql_fetch_assoc. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá @Davi,
Não sei se entendi direito o que você quer fazer, mas o problema pelo que notei está no seguinte trecho:

```
<?php $this->AppNoticiasDestaque = $verRow; ?>
```

Pois para cada vez que o código passa no loop você está substituindo tudo o que tem salvo pelo próxima linha, o que acaba resultando em apenas 1 registro.
Você pode resolver isso alterando o retorno do seu método para:

```
<?php $this->AppNoticiasDestaque[] = $verRow; ?>
```

Para que você tenha um array com todos os resultados, você pode testar usando isso:

```
<?
echo "<pre>";
print_r($obj->AppNoticiasDestaque);
?>
```

Acho que isso vai te ajudar.

Comment: William, perfeito! Era justamente esse o ‘problema’, estava quase desistindo já. Kk
Muitíssimo obrigado, ajudou muito mesmo. Parabéns pelo conhecimento aí, felicidades.